# Understanding the notion of proof by contradiction

Tags: logic

Let's imagine that we want to proof the following proposition:

$\forall_{q_1,q_2} P(q_1,q_2)\implies C(q_1,q_2)$.

The way I understand the prove by contradiction is the following:
We want to reach $\forall_{q_1,q_2} P(q_1,q_2) \land \lnot C(q_1,q_2)\implies \lnot P(q_1,q_2)$. 
Since the implication is true (assuming no errors in deduction), and knowing that $P(q_1,q_2)$ is true, we must have $\lnot C(q_1,q_2)$ as false. Therefore we must have $C(q_1,q_2)$ true.

Have I understood correctly the concept of proof by contradiction?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, in a proof by contradiction, you have to assume the *negation* of the statement to be proved.

Comment: So, if the staement to be prove is : $C(x,y)$ (without quantifiers ????) you have to assume $\lnot C(x,y)$ and derive a contradiction from it **and the other "active" assumptions** : axioms, already proven theorems, ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what about the quantifiers? Are they correct? or should I change them to $\exists$ ?  Also, the axioms or proven theorem is  the $P(q_1,q_2)$  part, right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA also could $P(q_1,q_2)$ be something as simple as $q_1 \in A$ and $q_2 \in B$, for nonempty sets $A,B$?

Comment: If you are working with the language of set, yes : $x \in A \land y \in B$ is of the "form" : $P(x,y)$. Thus, from the "axiom" $\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$ and the assumption $\lnot C$, if you derive a contradiction you can conclude that $C$ follows from the axiom, and thus with : $\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \Rightarrow C$.